# Cómo pasar datos a traves de window.location

Tags: php

A traves de inicio.php envio estas variables:

nombre, edad, sexo, ciudad

Que son recogidas y procesadas por procesa.php

```
$nombre = htmlspecialchars($_POST["nombre"]);
$edad = htmlspecialchars($_POST["edad"]);
$sexo = htmlspecialchars($_POST["sexo"]);
$ciudad = htmlspecialchars($_POST["ciudad"]);
```

para luego desde procesa.php enviar las variables a resultados.php lo cual lo hago de esta manera pero ya no me envia ningun valor:

```
$mensaje = "<script>window.location='resultados.php?nombre='+.'$nombre'.+'&edad='+ .'$edad'.'&sexo='+.'$sexo'.'&ciudad='+.'$ciudad'.';</script>";
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas  redirecciones desde PHP con [`header()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.header.php)?

Comment: Intenta algo así:  `header("Location: resultados.php?nombre=$nombre&edad=$edad&sexo=$sexo&ciudad=$ciudad");`

Comment: Debería usar [`urlencode`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.urlencode.php) sobre cada variable

Answer (score 0):

Mi forma de hacer esto es crear un array aparte (si hay valores del $_POST que no quieres enviar) y utilizar la función `http_build_query()`.

Quedaría así:

```
//convierto los índices del $_POST en variables sueltas, para ahorrarnos escribir el $_POST siempre.
extract($_POST);

//después creo un array en el que guardaré las variables extraídas.
//este paso y el anterior te los ahorras si el $_POST contiene únicamente los datos que quieres mandar en la URL.
$queryVals = array($nombre, $edad, $sexo, $ciudad);

//uso 'http_build_query()' para crear la cadena de consulta.
$queryStr = http_build_query($queryVals); 

//redirecciono con la función 'header()' mejor que imprimir javascript para esto.
header("Location: resultados.php?$queryStr");
```

Esto debería funcionarte bien.

Comment: Puede ser más comprimido si lo haces todo en una sola línea: `header("Location: resultados.php?".http_build_query(array($nombre, $edad, $sexo, $ciudad)));`. Yo así no te lo recomiendo por razones de legibilidad. Son 3 líneas chuflas asi que no me las ahorraría. Pero ya como tú lo necesites.